# this en un componente de clase en REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this

estoy viendo una clase sobre componentes de clase de React y explican que es preferible usar arrow functions para definir los métodos del componente:

Esto sería mejor

```
        onButtonClick = () => {
          console.log("this arrow", this);
          this.setState({
            contador: this.state.contador + 1,
          });
        };
```

Esta función

```
        onButtonClick(){
        
        this.setState({
        contador: this.state.contador + 1,
           });
         }
```

La explicación es que la arrow function se autobindea el objeto this al del scope en el que lo estoy creando, en este caso el modulo de clase, y en la función normal el this apuntaría al objeto global

Tenía entendido que usando las funciones normales al usar this apuntaba también dentro del módulo o clase donde fue creada, y al intentar probar en mi código

```
class Prueba {
    constructor(nombre){
        this.nombre = nombre
        this.state = {
            counter:0
        }
    }
    consola(){
        return this
    }  
}
const prueba = new Prueba("Nicolás")
console.log(prueba.consola())
```

Esto funciona y me retorna el el objeto clase Prueba "prueba"

Así que no entiendo por qué no funciona dentro de los módulos de clase de React. ¿Esto es una particularidad del metodo setState? ¿O de React?

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para JavaScript Class ...

En un método de clase JS el valor de `this` no está determinado por su `lexical scope` (como en react class `function expression`).

El valor del `this` de dicho método queda determinado en `runtime` dependiendo de como fue llamado.

Si el método fue llamado como instancia de la clase usando notación punto (tu caso) el valor de `this` apunta a la instancia:

```
const prueba = new Prueba("Nicolás")
console.log(prueba.consola()) //tu objeto this
```

Pero si el método es llamado sin contexto su valor `this` sera `undefined/objeto` global dependiendo de si esta activado o no `strict mode`.

```
const prueba = new Prueba("Nicolás")
console.log(prueba.consola) //undefined/global object
```